# How to make a redirect to nginx, depending on the part of the URL?

Tags: redirect, nginx, request, webserver, url-rewriting

Welcome essence of the problem.
We have a path

```
site.com/seveniry-dlya-turistov/...
```

(Where ... is the character code specific record (of goods), and in front of it, as you might guess - section of this article)
Those show on `site.com` website under "souvenirs for tourists" page of a souvenir.

I need to redirect this type:
If there is a request to `.../eveniry-dlya-turistov/..` substitute the section title in the name of `.../seveniry/...`, see if there is a request for

```
site.com/seveniry-dlya-turistov/elemnet1/
```

we have to do a 301 redirect to

```
site.com/seveniry/elemnet1/
```

Please tell me how to do it, and why does not work like that ...

```
location /catalog {
    rewrite ^/catalog/souvernirs-for-tourists/(.*)$ http://SITE-NAME/suveniry/$1 permanent;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like

```
rewrite ^/seveniry-dlya-turistov/(.*)$ /seveniry/$1 last;
```

But you need to test the exact regex since it's hard to do by head without testing. nginx will look for another location block matching /seveniry/$1 to serve content.